# Excluding tel and mailto in base target statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

Per a client request, we forced all external links to open in a new tab. Currently I am using a js script for that.

However, it is also forcing the tel and mailto links to open new tabs as well. And I think that is why I am getting an error on some devices when you click and email link, where a pop up box says "This website has been blocked from automatically composing an email" - that one was uncovered specifically on an iPhone 6.

How can I force external links- but exclude mail and telephone links? Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

This is the external link script that I am using currently. I thought maybe I could just make an alteration to look for only external links that had "http" but an else statement for tel and mailto. But I am not sure how I could go about that.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('a').each(function() {
        var a = new RegExp('/' + window.location.host + '/');
        if(!a.test(this.href)) {
            $(this).click(function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                event.stopPropagation();
                window.open(this.href, '_blank');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I'd say your method to open links is overcomplicated. Why do you not just modify all anchor elements to add or modify the target attribute? Instead of your `click` function, simply use: `$(this).attr('target', '_blank');`

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I replaced that line with the code you offered and I get the same result. External links open in a new tab- but that includes tel and mailto links. Is there another if statement I need to create? This might clean up my code, but it doesn't help me target those specific link types that I can see.

Comment: That's true, my comment was only focussing on improving your code without giving an answer to your question. See my answer to solve the issue you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combined with my comment, I would opt to go for a check against the `href` attribute of each anchor, and check that it does not start with `mailto:` or `tel:`: 
(and the external link is not working at all, I guess that is caused by the snippet environment)

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('a').each(function() {
        var a = new RegExp('/' + window.location.host + '/');
        if(!a.test(this.href) && this.href.substr(0,4)!='tel:' && this.href.substr(0,7)!='mailto:') {
            $(this).attr('target', '_blank');
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://www.google.com">website</a>,
<a href="mailto:someone@somewhere.com">e-mail</a> and
<a href="tel:123456789">phone</a>.
```

I must admit that it is not ideal to check for all protocols that you might want to exclude, but it definitely is easier than checking for everything that you would like to open in a new window/tab.

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you so much. I still have a lot to learn with javascript.