# Javascript causing some links not to work

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having an issue with this piece of JavaScript. The issue is that when it is enabled, some of my links aren't working. The links that open a webpage work fine, it's the mailto: and tel: links that won't work. Can someone please help me fix this issue? Thank you.

```
const allLinks = document.querySelectorAll("a:link");

allLinks.forEach(function (link) {
  link.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    
    // conditional for preventDefault
    if (link.hasAttribute("target") === false) {
        e.preventDefault();
    } else {
      if (link.getAttribute("target") !== "_blank") {
        e.preventDefault();
      }
    }

    const href = link.getAttribute("href");

    // Scroll back to top
    if (href === "#")
      window.scrollTo({
        top: 0,
        behavior: "smooth",
      });
```

Comment: Please revise to create a functional snippet including some HTML to demonstrate the problem. See [ask].

Comment: you can exclude tel: and mail: please see this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343665/excluding-tel-and-mailto-in-base-target-statement

Comment: The code looks suspicious. What's that supposed to do?

Comment: hijacking page links? why not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is preventing the link from being followed if it doesn't have a target attribute set to `"_blank"`.

Tel and mailto links don't usually have a target. As [@The Fool](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9208887/the-fool) mentioned, this looks suspicious and it's unclear how you expected it to work.

You can probably fix it by adding the following to the top of your handler.

```
if (link.href.startsWith("tel:")  || link.href.startsWith("mailto:")) {
    return
}
```